# Inconsistent spacing between header and top of figure

Tags: floats

Consider the image given below. Both figures had identical float environment:

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering
    \begin{overpic}...
```

The bottom one is aligned perfectly with small gap between top header and the top of image. All images in my thesis align the same way.

Except the one shown on top. It completely latches on to the header line.
Is there any was to correct it? at present I am using `~\\~\\` inside that particular float to shift it down a little.

[image: TOP:incorrectBOTTOM:correct]

Given below is the preamble, in case any setting there is offending one:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside,12pt]{report}

\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[square,numbers,sectionbib]{natbib}
\usepackage{chapterbib}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{float} 
\floatstyle{plaintop} 
\restylefloat{table} 
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{multirow}

% ==========================Header====================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}

\oddsidemargin 0.5cm \evensidemargin 0.5cm
\marginparwidth 40pt \marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 0pt \headsep 40pt
\textheight 650pt \textwidth 450pt
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
```

TLDR: How to make top image placement look like the one in bottom?

EDIT:
I have narrowed down the problem to the following: this only happens when i use image in `overpic` environment. For `\includefigure` its all good.

Minimal example with image and tex file (google drive link, am not sure i can upload image pdf here, GZIP compressed file in comments below, in case anyone on linux):

[ZIP](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6a5tpesi91KNXl6QzZpc1c2RjQ)

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of Judy sniplets. And remove stuff that uæis clearly not related to your  problem. Then it is a lot easier for others to test your problem without having to guess parts of your code.

Comment: Unrelated, don't set margins etc like that use the geometry package.

Comment: The margins were like that because currently it was under rivision, but i would definitely look into geometry package. here is the GZIP archive for example reproducing issue, [GZIP](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6a5tpesi91Kc0UzUUh0eUFKcVk), it has image as df file and tex file.

Comment: Damn, this is odd! If you really need to write stuff on that picture, maybe you can do that using TikZ for this particular figure instead of overpic. `\node[inner sep = 0pt] {\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{dummyfigure.pdf}};` Edit: I wrote that in an answer, but I hope someone will come with an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Emergency solution if you get sick of trying stuff:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openright,twoside,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic} % for writing put over figures

% ==========================Header====================================
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyheadoffset{0cm}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\oddsidemargin 0.5cm \evensidemargin 0.5cm
\marginparwidth 40pt \marginparsep 10pt
\topmargin 0pt \headsep 40pt
\textheight 650pt \textwidth 450pt
\setlength{\headsep}{5pt}
% =========================================================================

\doublespacing
\begin{document}
\blindtext[4]
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \centering%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep = 0pt] {\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{dummyfigure.pdf}};
        \node[scale = 4] {BLAH BLAH};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\blindtext[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that I added `\usepackage{tikz}`, of course, to use `tikzpicture`.

Edit: “improved” figure code with a command mimicking `\put` for this particular case (a picture with three lines of four squares):

```
\begin{figure}[!t]
    \newcommand{\fakeput}[3]{%
        \node at (-0.625\textwidth + #1 * 0.25\textwidth, 0.5\textwidth - #2 * 0.25\textwidth) {#3};
    }
    \centering%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[inner sep = 0pt] {\includegraphics[width = \textwidth]{dummyfigure.pdf}};
        \begin{scope}[font = \Huge \bfseries \color{white}]
            \fakeput{1}{1}{1; 1}
            \fakeput{2}{1}{2; 1}
            \fakeput{1}{2}{1; 2}
            \fakeput{3}{3}{3; 3}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

The `scope` is just to make the examples more visible by changing the font of the tikz commands that stand within this environment.

Comment: Actually, each image in grid will have some over imposed text. Any way to replicate \put ()? I mean write text to a coordinate

Comment: @ipcamit The image is at coordinates (0, 0) of the tikzpicture by default. You can place other nodes using coordinates with any unit you want, and use `\textwidth` to help place stuff.

Comment: @ipcamit Currently working on it, but it will quickly get dirty without a macro to serve as a wrapper, haha. First square of the second line: `\node at (-0.375\textwidth, 0) {BLAH BLAH};`

Comment: @ipcamit Done, kind of xD

Comment: Maybe by using `anchor = north west` on the node that contains the picture, the (0, 0) coordinates would be placed on its upper left corner and it would make the placement of other things easier.

Comment: Thank you! I will give it  spin tomorrow. Let us see if anyone can come up with explanation of whats going on here, else i will mark it as accepted answer.